# Maven flexmojos-maven-plugin fails with OutOfMemoryError even with -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flexmojos

I'll be answering my own question to provide bread crumbs for the next person who hits this:

**Problem**

x86Linux Maven build fails during flexmojos-maven-plugin with

```
load-config+=...flex-config.xml -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries...
-metadata.language+=en_US 
[INFO] Loading configuration file .../flex-config.xml

# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 37064 bytes for Chunk::new
[ERROR] OutOfMemoryError -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Increase system swap.  The flexmojos call out fo the flex compiler (a native executable that requires memory outside of that which is allocated for the JVM).  If you run low on memory and can't swap out maven's jvm them the flex compiler fails.

I added additional swap and was able to complete the build successfully.

from [enter link description here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/)

```
# create swap file
dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/swapfile.1 bs=1M count=2048
# Set Permissions
chmod 600 /opt/swapfile.1
# Define as swap
mkswap /opt/swapfile.1
# Add to active swap
swapon /opt/swapfile.1
# Verify
free -m
```